# Can't create the [jsts] tag as the [jst] tag exists

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

I was tagging [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118883/using-jsts-buffer-to-identify-a-self-intersecting-polygon) which is about the [jsts geometry library](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts).

I wasn't allowed to use the [jsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsts) tag because the [jst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jst) tag exists.

The [jst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jst) tag doesn't have a description but the questions tagged with it appear to be about a JavaScript templating something... but certainly not a geometry library.

The site suggested I should post here if I thought the jsts tag should be allowed...

Comment: Something went wrong with a [giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/158100)?

Comment: The trouble with acronyms - reloaded.

Comment: Could be... JTS does stand for Java Topology Suite and so I assume JSTS for javascript topology suite... but JTS questions all use the tag jts and none use javatopologysuite or jtopologysuite so I assume jsts is more discoverable. But this is the first time I've ever thought about tags really

Comment: A bunch of the [jst] questions actually look like they should have been [jstl]. But that's also unrelated to the [jsts]